# How to rerender only a component and not the whole screen in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    ActivityIndicator,
    TextInput,
    Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import {RightOfHeader} from '../assets/components/rightOfHeader';

import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';
import TeekaPDF from '../assets/components/teekaPdf';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {setAngNum} from '../redux/actions';
import {allColors} from '../assets/styleForEachOption';

export default function OpenPdf({navigation, route}) {
    const [totalAngs, setTotalAngs] = React.useState(0);
    const [currentAng, setCurrentAng] = React.useState(1);
    const [showHeader, setShowHeader] = React.useState(true);

    const currentAngRef = React.useRef(1); //only for addListner

    const state = useSelector(theState => theState.theReducer);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const {pdfTitle} = route.params;

    const fileName = pdfTitle.split(' ').join(''); //replaces " " with ""
    const sourceFileName = {uri: state.allPdfs[pdfTitle].uri};


    React.useEffect(() => {
        //pick up where you left off from last time
        //this.pdf.setPage(state.allPdfs[pdfTitle].currentAng);
        navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', () => {
            dispatch(setAngNum(pdfTitle, currentAngRef.current));
        });
    }, [totalAngs, navigation]);

    const headerStyles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        },
        title: {
            flex: 1,
            margin: 10,
            borderRadius: 5,
            height: '75%',
            backgroundColor: '#077b8a',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            textAlign: 'center',
        },
        pagesBox: {
            flex: 1.5,
            margin: 10,
            borderRadius: 5,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            // justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
            fontSize: 20,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: '#077b8a',
        },
        setAngNumBox: {
            borderRadius: 5,
            height: '95%',
            fontSize: 20,
            backgroundColor: '#a2d5c6',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            textAlign: 'center',
        },
        boxText: {
            fontSize: 25,
        },
        headerBtnsCont: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
        },
        headerBtns: {
            flex: 1,
            paddingTop: 20,
        },
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let showTitle = pdfTitle;
        if (showTitle.length > 15) showTitle = showTitle.slice(0, 15) + '...';
        console.log("YOYOYOO")
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown: showHeader,
            headerTintColor: state.darkMode ? 'white' : 'black',
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: allColors[state.darkMode].headerColor,
            },
            headerTitle: () => {
                return (
                    <View style={headerStyles.container}>
                        <Text style={headerStyles.title}>{showTitle}</Text>
                        <View style={headerStyles.pagesBox}>
                            <TextInput
                                keyboardType="numeric"
                                value={currentAng.toString()}
                                style={headerStyles.setAngNumBox}
                                placeholder="ex: 5"
                                onChangeText={text => {
                                    if (text.length === 0) {
                                        setCurrentAng('');
                                    } else if (text.length < 5) {
                                        setCurrentAng(parseInt(text));
                                    }
                                }}
                                onSubmitEditing={e => {
                                    const asInt = currentAng;
                                    if (asInt) {
                                        //this.pdf.setPage(asInt);
                                        if (asInt > totalAngs) {
                                            setCurrentAng(totalAngs);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }}
                            />
                            <Text style={headerStyles.boxText}>
                                /{totalAngs}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                );
            },
            
        });
    });

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: allColors[state.darkMode].mainBackgroundColor,
        },
        pdf: {
            width: '100%',
            height: '99%',
            borderRadius: 15,
        },
    });
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Pdf
                ref={pdf => {
                    //this.pdf = pdf;
                }}
                activityIndicator={
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="blue" />
                }
                source={sourceFileName}
                onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
                    setTotalAngs(numberOfPages);
                }}
                onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => {
                    if (
                        showHeader &&
                        state.hideHeaderOnScroll &&
                        page > currentAng
                    ) {
                        setShowHeader(false);
                    }
                    setCurrentAng(page);
                }}
                onPageSingleTap={() => {
                    setShowHeader(!showHeader);
                }}
                onError={error => {
                    Alert.alert(
                        'PDF ERROR',
                        String(error),
                        [
                            {
                                text: 'Cancel',
                                style: 'cancel',
                            },
                        ],
                        {
                            cancelable: true,
                        },
                    );
                }}
                onPressLink={uri => {
                    console.log(`Link presse: ${uri}`);
                }}
                style={styles.pdf}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

The problem I'm receiving is when the page changes, it goes to the 'onPageChanged' function and in the function I have a setter hook setCurrentAng(page). This changes the current page number for the user in headerTitle. It has no effect on the pdf. I have a variable CurrentAng which shows the user the current page number of the pdf. SetCurrentAng changes the CurrentAng to show the current page number. When I scroll to a new page(when pageChanged), It is very choppy and not smooth. This is because when the page is changed, I set the current page number which makes everything rerender again and making it choppy. when I comment 'setCurrentAng(page);' in onPageChanged function, the pdf scrolls smoothly but then i am not able to see which page number I am on. Please forgive me for my lack of knowladge and mistakes. Thanks for reading this. Hope you can help